# mongoose find results not refreshing

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, pug

I'm working with express/jade/mongodb to create a site with a db (pretty new in this).
I am retrieving a list from the db using 'mongoose find' during the get method using this function:

```
function getBookList(Book, req, callback){
  Book.find({'username': req.user.username}, 'bookTitle author', function(err, userBooks) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    else if (userBooks.length > 0) {
      bookList.push(userBooks);
      callback();
    }
  });
};

router.get('/', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res, next) {
 getBookList(Book, req, function(){
      res.locals.user.books = bookList[0];
      res.render('index', { title: 'library' });
  });
});
```

In my jade file the code is:

```
ul
    each book in user.books
        li #{book.bookTitle}
            span  -  
            span #{book.author}
```

The first time I log in with a user I get the list as expected, but if I add a document to the db and render the page again, the list on my page doesn't update and stays as it was.
Even after a logout and another login it stays the same. Only after restarting the server the list will update.
can anyone explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each call to `getBookList`, you are pushing the resulting array of books into another array, `bookList`.

So say that you have one document in the database and call `getBookList`. Afterwards, `bookList` will look something like this:

```
bookList = [ [ 'book 1' ] ]
```

Then you add another book, and call `getBookList` again. Now `bookList` looks like this:

```
bookList = [ [ 'book 1' ], [ 'book 1', 'book 2' ] ]
```

However, you are only ever using `bookList[0]`, so the result of the first call to `getBookList`. This will never contain new documents, because those will only appear in later entries to `bookList`.

That's not the biggest problem to solve though, because you're using `bookList` as a global variable, which isn't a good idea. Instead, `getBookList` should pass the list of books back to the caller.

That would make the code look something like this:

```
function getBookList(username, callback){
  Book.find({'username': username}, 'bookTitle author', function(err, userBooks) {
    callback(err, userBooks);
  });
};

router.get('/', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res, next) {
 getBookList(req.user.username, function(err, userBooks) { 
  if (err) return handleError(err);
  else if (userBooks.length > 0) {
    res.locals.user.books = userBooks;
    res.render('index', { title: 'library' });
  } else {
    // handle the situation where no books were found
    ...
  }
});
```

There are also some other changes, like decoupling `getBookList` from the model (`Book`) and the request (`req`).